# regular expression: replace match with its index

Tags: regex, string, replace

How can I transform the string "a b a c d a a" into the string "1 b 2 c d 3 4" with a regular expression?

Is this possible? Preferred flavor is perl, but any other will do too.

```
s/a/ \????? /g
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This substitution will do it.

```
$ perl -p -e 's/a/++$i/ge' 
a b a c d a a
1 b 2 c d 3 4
```

- e   Evaluate the right side as an expression.
- g   Replace globally, i.e., all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

In Java regex, you'd use a `Matcher.find()` loop, using `Matcher.appendReplacement/Tail`, which currently takes only `StringBuffer`.

So, something like this works ([see also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/jrLii)):

```
    String text = "hahaha that's funny; not haha but like huahahuahaha";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(hu?a){2,}").matcher(text);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int index = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb,
            String.format("%S[%d]", m.group(), ++index)
        );
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    // prints "HAHAHA[1] that's funny; not HAHA[2] but like HUAHAHUAHAHA[3]"
```

#### API links

- [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

#### See also

- [BugID: 5066679 - `java.util.regex.Matcher` should make more use of `Appendable`](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5066679)